# Loading 2 dropdownlists using 2 separate datareaders

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, sqldatareader

This is probably a very basic question.Anyways here goes. I am trying to use 2 data readers to load 2 dropdownlists 'lstState' and 'lstCity'.

```
string connectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM STATES",SqlConn);
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

try 
{ 
    SqlConn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdrSql = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    lstState.DataSource = rdrSql;
    lstState.DataTextField = "STATE";
    lstState.DataValueField = "";

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lstState.DataBind();
    }

    rdrSql.Close();
}
```

At present the dropdownlist 'lstState' is getting loaded fine.But,if I remove the comments related to 'lstCity' ,neither 'lstState' not 'lstCity' is getting loaded.Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both readers are associated with the same connection you have to dispose / close the first before procceding to second, try:

```
...
SqlDataReader rdrSql = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
rdrSql.Close();
SqlDataReader rdrSql2 = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();
```